# Bukkit; How to trigger multiple ClickEvent RUN_COMMAND actions with a single click on a single chat message

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've written a rather simple method for my paper/spigot Minecraft server plugin that detects potential lag machines under construction.

The issue I have is that **I want to send a *single* chat message that, when clicked once, will first run a `/vanish` command** on behalf of the clicker.

Then if (and only **if) the vanish was successful, I want to run a teleport command** to a location included along with the specific instance of the `ClickEvent`.

### Both of those commands need to be completed from the single user click event.

For reference here is the method that calls `notifyOps()` and includes the TextComponent in question, `msg`

```
        if (LagMats.contains(blockType) || mat.contains("MINECART") || mat.contains("DOOR")) {
            int counter = 0;

            for (Material thisMat: LagMats) {
                if (thisMat != Material.GRAVEL) {
                    counter += Utilities.blockCounter(block.getChunk(), thisMat);
                }
            }

            TextComponent warn = new TextComponent("WARN "); warn.setBold(true);
            warn.setColor(ChatColor.RED);

            TextComponent msg = new TextComponent("Potential lag-machine at " +
                    block.getX() + ", " + block.getY() + ", " + block.getZ() + " in " + dimension +
                    " by " + placer_name + " with UUID: " + placer.getUniqueId());

            String cmd = "/execute in " + env + " run tp @s " +
                    block.getX() + " " + block.getY() + " " + block.getZ();

            msg.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, cmd));

            if (counter > 256) {
                Utilities.notifyOps(new TextComponent(warn, msg));
            }
        }
```

Oh and the actual little code of `notifyOps` where the `TextComponent` is used in a message:

```
    // send a message to all online ops and console
    public static boolean notifyOps(TextComponent msg) {
        if (msg == null) return false;

        for (Player thisPlayer: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            try {
                if (thisPlayer.isOp()) thisPlayer.spigot().sendMessage(msg);
            } catch (Exception e) {return false;}
        }
        System.out.println(msg.getText());
        return true;
    }
```

So I want to have the user click just once, run two commands, the second only if the first succeeds, and would be best if it could be done within the try block the message is sent from.

I *could* write a custom command for this purpose, and then just run that command, but I rather avoid adding classes for such a small addition if it's actually possible and I just have no idea.

Thanks for any advice or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There is no way of doing that without writing a custom command...

This is impossible because the `ClickEvent` and `HoverEvent` are entirely client-side. That means that there are no packets sent from the `Player` to the server. Therefore, it is impossible to callback the click of the `Player` and call a method to perform what you are trying to do.

You may notice that all the `ClickEvent.Action`s do not affect the server. `OPEN_URL`, `OPEN_FILE`, `RUN_COMMAND`, `SUGGEST_COMMAND`, `CHANGE_PAGE` and `COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD` are all actions taken on the client-side.

The only way here is to make the client send a command to the server which will trigger a method.